# cannot find symbol error javac command

Tags: java

I am using terminal to compile and build java programs.
So I have 2 classes `CP1` and `CP2` belong to package name `current` that are implemented in 2 separate .java files - `CP1.java` and `CP2.java`
Although classes are trivial, here is the code

CP1.java :

```
package current;
public class CP1{
                  void hello(){
                               System.out.println("CP1 class is used");
                  }
   }
```

CP2.java :

```
package current;
public class CP2{
                  public static void main(String [] args){
                               System.out.println("CP2 class is used");
                               CP1 c= new CP1();
                  }
   }
```

As CP1 and CP2 are defined in the same package i do not import the current package. Both .java files are in the same directory. CP1.java compiles and the result is CP1.class file. Now I am trying to compile CP2.java with with -cp option as:

```
javac -cp . CP2.java
```

However, this results in the error message:

```
symbol: class CP1    
location: class CP2
CP2.java.  error: cannot find symbol 
                  CP1=new CP1
```

I tried various paths to cp but still get the same error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't  class name of your CP2.java  should be class CP2

Comment: sure, this typo

Comment: read the updated answer, i have tested it , worked plus make sure no typo

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the instance variable name so it should be this

```
CP1  objname = new CP1();
```

not this

```
CP1 = new CP1();
```

Note : `objname` can be replaced with any valid variable name so you can search online for naming guidelines/how to name a variable or can try [Official doc link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Update : follow the below steps to compile

1.) Seems like you are at the location where the file exists so simply do this

```
javac -d . CP1.java

javac -d . CP2.java
```

`-d` will generate the package for you if it's not there.

Comment: sorry, in the original code CP1 c= new CP1(), of course

Comment: @olzhabala u can accept my answer by clicking on tick sumbol (on left) to thank me.happy coding